# Location of Validation Message

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In [this guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) that I was attempting to follow, validation messages show up to the right and are red. Mine appear dull and to the left, as in the picture below.

[image]

I have read and reread the guide I linked to, but I can't see any major difference between his code and mine. Why do my `Label` and `TextBox` show up in the order I created them, while my validation messages show up in between?

Here is (what I believe to be) the relevant part of my model

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]        
    [Display(Name="IP Address")]
    public string address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "TCP Port")]
    public int port { get; set; }
```

and the corresponding part of my View.

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.address):
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.address)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.address)
</p>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.port):
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.port)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.port)
</p>
```

I realize that typical validation on items like these would be more robust. For now, my only concern is that they did not leave the field blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Input` boxes were somehow given the property `float: right`. The validation messages, by default, float left. By removing the float property of the Inputs, the validation messages are now showing up to the right of the Inputs.

Furthermore, by pressing F12 in the browser while the project is running, one can view the styles being applied to elements. Additionally, one can just right-click the element and "inspect element". I at least confirmed that alternative in Chrome and IE10.

Hopefully that trick will help someone else avoid looking at MVC for problems caused by a ninja CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this to your main css file?

```
 .input-validation-error
 {
     border: 1px solid #ff0000;
     background-color: #ffeeee;
 }
.field-validation-error {
   background-color:white;
   border-radius:4px;
   border: solid 1px #333;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top:0; right:0; left:0;
   text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion has made my **input** a beautiful red color. However, my validation **message** is still in the same place.

Comment: I have updated my answer - check it now. In case it won't help in your particular case please paste the whole view file (or at least the part surrounding your validation extensions).

Comment: Not surprisingly, adding your new style now has my validation message showing up at absolute coordinates (0,0). I added my own answer to the question, because I finally figured it out. Some other CSS was floating my elements, and because I'm new to CSS and HTML I didn't catch know how to inspect them in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue. The validation message for my first input box was right aligned while all the rest were left aligned. Updating my style sheet with the code below fixed the problem.

```css
.field-validation-error {
   display: block;
   text-align:right;
}
```